# Print the number of unique pairs Stored in a HashSet

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I'm trying to solve this fairly straight forward challenge:

> **Problem Statement**
>
> In computer science, a set is an abstract data type that can store
>   certain values, without any particular order, and no repeated
>   values. {1,2,3} is an example of a set, but {1,2,2} is not
>   a set. Today you will learn how to use sets in java by solving this
>   problem.
>
> You are given n pairs of strings. Two pairs (a,b) and (c,d) are
>   identical if a=b and c=d. That also implies (a,b) is not same as
>   (b,a). After taking each pair as input, you need to print number of
>   unique pairs you currently have.
>
> Note: Brute force solution will not earn full points.

This works, but I'm getting a timeout on the last test case (10.000 elements to go through).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Set<Pair> pairs = new HashSet<>();
        final int N = s.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            String first = s.next();
            String second = s.next();

            pairs.add(new Pair(first, second));
            System.out.println(pairs.size());
        }       
    }

    public static class Pair {
        String first, second;
        Pair(String first, String second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }

        @Override public int hashCode() {
            return first.hashCode();
        }

        @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
            if (other == this) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!(other instanceof Pair)) {
                return false;
            }

            Pair otherPair = (Pair) other;
            return (first.equals(otherPair.first) && second.equals(otherPair.second))
                || (first.equals(otherPair.second) && second.equals(otherPair.first));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem's definition of equality seems broken.  If (a,b)=(c,d) => a=b and c=d, then (a,b)=(c,d) => (b,a)=(c,d) by definition. But the problem specifically says that (a,b) and (b,a) are not identical.  I'm fairly certain it's supposed to be "a=c and b=d".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly, janos solution is the simplest, but it'd probably break for the input

```
a b
a  b
```

Moreover, it circumvents the learning effect (I guess, it's about learning to write a class with `equals` and `hashCode`).

As often, [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html) makes it trivial:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
public static class Pair {
    private final String first, second;
}
```

### hashCode

The inefficiency was most probably caused by

```
@Override public int hashCode() {
    return first.hashCode();
}
```

which is correct, but leads to many collisions due to ignoring `second`. Something like

```
    return first.hashCode() + 123456789 * second.hashCode();
```

would solve it (the multiplier should be odd, anything else doesn't matter much).

### equals

```
  return (first.equals(otherPair.first) && second.equals(otherPair.second))
            || (first.equals(otherPair.second) && second.equals(otherPair.first));
```

This contradicts the part

> implies (a,b) is **not** same as (b,a).

If it ever worked, then only because of the asymmetry in `hashCode`.

#### Why?

Two `equals` objects must have the same `hashCode`, otherwise the `HashSet` doesn't work properly (as the hash determines the index where the lookup starts). Violating this rule is a serious bug with which you may spend many funny debugging days.

This time, it helped you. After

```
set.put(new Pair("a", "b"));
```

the query

```
set.contains(new Pair("b", "a"));
```

erroneously returns false, although according to `equals`, the pair is there. However, it doesn't get found due to the non-equal `hashCode`. Analogously, after

```
set.put(new Pair("b", "a"));
```

you managed to contradict

> set is an abstract data type that can store certain values, without any particular order, and **no repeated values**.

Note that this is not guaranteed to happen as the hashes may coincide and only a part of them gets used.

Comment: What do you mean by the last line in your answer?

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. Is it enough to remove this part of the equals? `|| (first.equals(otherPair.second) && second.equals(otherPair.first)`?

Comment: @Nilzone- For correctness, yes. For speed, I'd suggest to change the `hashCode` as well as ignoring one half of the pair is too bad. Use `first.hashCode() - second.hashCode()` if you're scared of the multiplication (`+` is slightly worse because of the symmetry).

Comment: One more question. When I used `first.hashCode() + second.hashCode()` I got the wrong answer on some of the test cases. Why do you think that is?

Comment: @Nilzone- Re-read my last paragraph. Your `hashCode` matched your `equals` (both were symmetrical), so this part worked correctly. But your `equals` didn't match what you should do. +++ With your working code, there were two bugs sort of cancelling each other.

Answer (score 4):

Given the problem description,
it seems you don't need to worry about pairs at all.
You can simply shove all data lines into a `Set`,
and finally print the size:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Set<String> lines = new HashSet<>();
    final int N = s.nextInt();
    s.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        lines.add(s.nextLine());
    }       
    System.out.println(lines.size());
}
```

Unless, the `n` pairs of strings are not on individual lines,
but you in fact have a sequence of integers on one line.
In that case you can adapt the main loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        lines.add(s.nextInt() + ":" + s.nextInt());
    }
```

Comment: oh my god.... You're absolutely right. I'm feeling pretty stupid right now. It's way to easy to think the problem is much worse than what it actually is.

Comment: I guess, I could break you code via `a b\na  b`.

Answer (score 3):

Since [@janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90933/27975) and [@maaartinus](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90937/27975) have adequately covered the performance concerns, I'll touch on two other supplementary things:

1. **`try-with-resources`**

   You should use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) on your `Scanner` object:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. **`Objects` utility class from Java 7**

   Since you are already using Java 7, you can consider using the [`Objects`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) utility class to greatly standardize the way to do `hashCode()` and `equals()`:

   ```
   public static final class Pair {

       private final String[] pair;
       private final int hashCode;

       public Pair(String first, String second) {
           pair = new String[] { first, second };
           hashCode = Objects.hash(first, second);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object o) {
           return o instanceof Pair && Objects.deepEquals(pair, ((Pair) o).pair);
       }

       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           return hashCode;
       }
   }
   ```

   Since the pair of `String`s are expected to remain immutable, you can create an array of out them to facilitate the [`deepEquals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#deepEquals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) usage ***and*** also pre-compute the hash code by using [`hash(Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash-java.lang.Object...-). These cuts down on the 'boilerplate-like' code you'll be required to write for the two `String` values otherwise. I've chosen to make the class `final` so that you can be sure `instanceof` will only work for `Pair` instances.